dns_rdata_fromtext /etc/bind/zones unexpected end of input
Hello i have problem with this kinf of error: dns_rdata_fromtext /etc/bind/zones/db.fwd.petar.local failed: unexpected end of input this is my file: Any sugestions how to fix this issue?
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns.petar.local. root.ns.petar.local. (
5
604800
86400
2419200
604800 )
; name servers
IN      NS      ns.petar.local.
30.10      IN      PTR    ns.petar.local.
enter image description here
enter image description here

Is that the same file? That doesn't look like the same file.
